# Creating singularity container with nextflow

Tags: scientific-computing, singularity-container, nextflow

I am trying to build a singularity container with nextflow installed. After doing the build I install it in a dir and it is installed as ROOT. When I try to run the container it fails since I am not root. I looked over the best practices and it says the following:

*Always install packages, programs, data, and files into operating system locations (e.g. not /home, /tmp , or any other directories that might get commonly binded on).*

My def file:

```
BootStrap: yum
OSVersion: 7
MirrorURL: http://mirror.centos.org/centos-%{OSVERSION}/%{OSVERSION}/os/$basearch/
Include: yum

%post
    yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless
    yum -y install wget
    yum -y install which

    mkdir /s2fast
    cd /s2fast
    wget -qO- https://get.nextflow.io | bash

%runscript
    exec /s2fast/nextflow
```

Running it gets me 'Permission Denied'
I'm running singularity 3.4.0-1

Not sure if I should be looking at using bind paths, overlays, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your container only needs [Nextflow](https://www.nextflow.io/), may I suggest using the Nextflow biocontainer from [quay.io](https://quay.io/repository/biocontainers/nextflow?tab=tags)?

```
singularity pull docker://quay.io/biocontainers/nextflow:19.07.0--hecc5488_0
```

If you need to install other apps along with Nextflow, usually one would install these into `/usr/local/bin`. But there's nothing wrong with using custom directory paths like what you are doing. In any case, you need to make sure these apps have the necessary permissions. Just add `chmod 755 /s2fast/nextflow` to your [%post](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.4/user-guide/definition_files.html#post) section. Also remove your [%runscript](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.4/user-guide/definition_files.html#runscript) section. It's not usually needed unless you need to process command-line arguments.

Comment: Well it looks like I did some variation of PBKAC because the chmod seems to work. I was using chmod earlier but it never seemed to work correctly. Also, I need to install alot of bio software so I need to role my own. But thanks for the heads up.